# Ebbinghaus like model for retention of details from experience

Tags: learning, memory

I've come across the [Ebbinghaus Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forgetting_curve) (forgetting curve) showing the retention of learned knowledge over time, but I wondered if there was the same kind of model for the retention of details from experiences over time, i.e., how much detail of an event does someone forget as time passes.

One would guess the same kind of curve may have been produced for this but I'm unsure what to look for.

Comment: Worth to note this [forgetting curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forgetting_curve) is _hypothesized_ to model the retention of learned knowledge, and does not seem to generalize all that well, even specifically so (according to Wikipedia) for some memories.

Comment: Recollection of personal experiences is a pretty broad topic and depends a lot on the nature of the experience. For example, if the experience is routine or traumatizing. Could you be more specific about what types of experiences you're interested in?

Comment: Perhaps check out [this](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/9859/do-distractors-create-false-learning-in-multiple-choice-questions/9947#9947) answer, as the references discuss knowledge retention (though pesented specifically in the context of distractors).